# ireport 3.7.4 on netbeans 6.9.1 won't execute

Tags: netbeans, jasper-reports, ireport, netbeans-6.9, jbutton

I'm new to java and jasperreport. I have a hard time executing a small report. I've added all the required jar file and encountered no errors.

How can I produce a pdf file using netbeans auto generated "mouseclicked" event of a jbutton?
Following is the code I've been working from the tutorial of thainetbeans and ireport tutorial site:

```
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.*;
import net.sf.jasperreports.view.*;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.*;

public class MyiReportViewer extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /** Creates new form MyiReportViewer */
    final String JDBC = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    final String DB = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/afemdb?user=root&password";
    private Connection con;
    /** Creates new form NewJPanel */
    public MyiReportViewer() {
        initComponents();
        try{
            Class.forName(JDBC).newInstance();
             con =DriverManager.getConnection(DB);
        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }
    }

    /** This method is called from within the constructor to
     * initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
     * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");
        jButton1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jButton1MouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(95, 95, 95)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(230, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(72, 72, 72)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(205, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        


    private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
        // TODO add your handling code here:
       try{
            //JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Lelou\\Desktop\\presentation\\InstructorQuestionaire.jrxml");
            //JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
            //JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint, true);


              JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Lelou\\Desktop\\presentation\\InstructorQuestionaire.jrxml");
              JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, null, con);
              JRViewer viewer = new JRViewer(print);
              viewer.setOpaque(true);
              viewer.setVisible(true);

            }
        catch(Exception e){

        }
    }                                     

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
            // TODO add your handling code here:
            // try{
           // JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Lelou\\Desktop\\presentation\\InstructorQuestionaire.jrxml");
            // JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
           // JasperPrint  jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, null, con);
           // JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint, true);


          //JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Lelou\\Desktop\\presentation\\InstructorQuestionaire.jrxml");
          //JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report,null, con);
          //JRViewer viewer = new JRViewer(print);
          //viewer.setOpaque(true);
          //viewer.setVisible(true);

          //  }
          // catch(Exception e){
          //}
    }                                        

    /**
    * @param args the command line arguments
    */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MyiReportViewer().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    // End of variables declaration                   

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this in your jButton1ActionPerformed method. You do not need the MouseClickedEvent.

```
try {
    URL reportFileURL = getClass().getResource("C:/Documents and Settings/Lelou/Desktop/presentation/InstructorQuestionaire.jrxml");
    File reportFile = new File(reportFileURL.toURI());
    JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(reportFile);
    JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, null, con);
    JasperViewer jv = new JasperViewer(jasperPrint);
    JDialog viewer = new JDialog(this, "Batch Report", true);
    viewer.setBounds(jv.getBounds());
    viewer.getContentPane().add(jv.getContentPane());
    viewer.setResizable(true);
    viewer.setIconImage(jv.getIconImage());
    viewer.setVisible(true);
} catch (JRException exc) {
   System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
} catch (URISyntaxException exs) {
   System.out.println(exs.getMessage());
}
```

(*) Note the slashes at the path-name. Get rid of the double back-slashes!

Here are your imports:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.JDialog;

import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JasperDesign;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader;
import net.sf.jasperreports.view.JasperViewer;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
```

Here are the libraries you need (i use iReport 4.0.1):

[image]
Most of them are here: **C:\Program Files\JasperSoft\iReport-4.0.1\ireport\modules\ext**

Check your connection string. In doubt use this constructor:

```
public MyiReportViewer() {
    initComponents();
    try {
        Class.forName(JDBC);
        //con =DriverManager.getConnection(DB);
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/afemdb?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8",
                    "root", "password");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Con " + e);
        }

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("SQL" + e);
    }
}
```

If it still does not work, there must be something wrong with your iReport.

Comment: do i need to import a package...got this error                                                       symbol  : class URL

    URL reportFileURL = getClass().getResource("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Lelou\\Desktop\\presentation\\InstructorQuestionaire.jrxml");                                                                            and                                                                                    symbol  : class URISyntaxException

} catch (URISyntaxException exs) {                                      apologies on my layout

Comment: another error occur...Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException...thanks Costis for helping me this on out ^^

Comment: no error on the LOC...it occurs after pressing the button...the output error is to large to post here...T_T

Comment: Con java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)                                                       your right...there's a problem on the connection...i'll just go tommorow my groupmate who did the schema and ask for the right string..hoping after that my ireport will work...thanks again Costis for the detailed help ^^

Comment: Great! If you get the connection right it will work. Never leave the catch blocks empty when you deal with databases.